# Connect two routers with different subnet

Tags: networking, router, routing

How can two routers be connected so that their client's can connect with each other?

Router A (cisco RV340) - Connected with ISP A has subnet 192.168.1.1/24. This router is connected to a switch to which all LAN devices connect.

Router B (cisco RV340) - Connected with ISP B has subnet 192.168.2.1/24. This router is connected with WIFI infrastructure in access point configuration.

Router A is used for LAN devices and Router B is used for wifi devices. We want wifi devices to also be able to connect with LAN devices and vice versa.

Comment: Just to make sure: you know that almost all link-local discovery stuff won't work across routers, right? // Do these routers support port-based VLANs?

Comment: @DanielB Link discovery won't work, that's okay. Yes, this router supports port-based VLAN.

Comment: Make sure what you are doing reflects computer design. Numerous computers now are Wireless Only (what I am using here). Consider keeping business machines on one subnet (we do that and we have the same Cisco router). Then set up guest access for smart phones. Having two subnets for business machines is troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say these routers support port-based VLANs, so I’d do it like this:

- Set up a port-based VLAN (untagged) on both routers with the same subnet but different IPs (for example 192.168.3.1/24 on Router A and 192.168.3.2/24 on Router B), DHCP etc not required
- Connect the VLAN’s physical ports on both routers using an Ethernet cable
- Set up static routes

  - *192.168.1.0/24* via *192.168.3.1* on Router B
  - *192.168.2.0/24* via *192.168.3.2* on Router A
- If needed, configure the firewalls to allow traffic between the “normal” network and the VLAN network

Devices should then be able to talk to each other using ping and whatever. As mentioned in the comment, discovery features like Chromecast, Windows Network Neighborhood, … will not work and in most cases cannot be made to work.

Comment: You don't need a 3rd subnet or VLAN tagging. In this case it can be even simpeler. See my answer

Comment: The VLAN needs to be either tagged or untagged on both ends. The “regular ports” (VLAN 1) should always be untagged in SOHO scenarios to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

On router A create an extra VLAN and put 1 of the LAN-ports in that VLAN.
Give that VLAN interface in router A an ip-address in the 192.168.2.1 range.
Connect that port to a port on router B.
On router B define a static route pointing 192.168.1.0/24 to the ip-address given to the VLAN addresses on router A.

That's it.

Please note that link-local stuff and other broadcast mechanisms won't pass accross routers.
And both routers will do DNS for their own LAN and the internet, but won't know about each others clients. That may also cause some issues.